# OpenMP startup code for benchmarking?

Tags: openmp, benchmarking

I'm attempting to benchmark the speedup for OpenMP aware code. I'm using the [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) library, and the [Rabin-Williams signature class](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_r_w_s_s.html). The class implements Bernstein's [Tweaked Roots](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf), and has the following code:

```
ModularArithmetic modp(m_p), modq(m_q);

#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_2_9p = modp.Exponentiate(2, (9 * m_p - 11)/8);
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_2_3q = modq.Exponentiate(2, (3 * m_q - 5)/8);
    #pragma omp section
        m_pre_q_p = modp.Exponentiate(m_q, m_p - 2);
}
```

From Crypto++'s perspective, all I need to do is something like the following:

```
RWSS<P1363_EMSA2, SHA256>::Signer signer(...);
signer.Precompute();

// Ready to sign
```

After I perform `Precompute()`, then Crypto++ is ready to go. I can sign away.

I also understand OpenMP has to startup, and it has things like dynamic teams. I tried to reference previous benchmarking papers, like [Performance Evaluation of OpenMP Benchmarks on Intel's Quad Core Processors](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2010/Corfu/COMPUTERS/COMPUTERS1-53.pdf), but they don't call out what they did. I also grepped sources like [EPCC OpenMP micro-benchmark suite](http://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/research/computing/performance-characterisation-and-benchmarking/epcc-openmp-micro-benchmark-suite), but it does not call `omp_set_dynamic` to remove the associated overhead.

What steps should I perform to get OpenMP into a clean room-like state so that I'm actually measuring the speedup of the big integer/signing operations, and not spending time in OpenMP startup or shutdown code; or spending time growing or shrinking the team? What do I do for OpenMP?

Comment: Loop over the timing a bunch of times, discard the first iteration and average the rest.

Comment: @Jeff - I thought about that. But if the teams grow and shrink, or thread pools (is that what they are called?) within a team change, then it may not be a complete mediation to the problem.

Comment: If this is the only part of the code that you want to benchmark, why not prepare multiple projects, each with a little more OMP code? i.e. 1) No omp; 2) Add `#pragma omp parallel` only (gives the overhead of creating the threads) 3) Add `#pragma omp sections` (gives the speedup); etc. Obviously, measure many times and average.